# Any way to restrict ASP.NET Core 2.0 HTTPS to TLS 1.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 REST server running fine, but I need to restrict access to TLS1.2 - how do I do this?  Can't seem to find any documentation on it.
Server is running on Kestrel.
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a [`UseHttps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.kestrelserveroptionshttpsextensions.usehttps?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_KestrelServerOptionsHttpsExtensions_UseHttps_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_KestrelServerOptions_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Https_HttpsConnectionFilterOptions_) overload that allows you to provide a [`HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.https.httpsconnectionadapteroptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0) instance to configure this. Here's an example of what this might look like in your case:

```
listenOptions.UseHttps(new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions
{
    ...
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
});
```

For reference, `SslProtocols` [defaults](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Kestrel.Https/HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions.cs#L25) to `SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11`.

Answer (score 6):

.NET Core 2.1 Kestrel config:

```
.UseKestrel(c =>
            {
                c.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opt =>
                {
                    opt.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                });
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 3.1, you can force TLS 1.2 by adding code below inside ConfigureWebHostDefaults in Program.cs

```
   webBuilder.UseKestrel(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.AddServerHeader = false;
                        opt.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(s =>
                        {
                            s.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                        });
                    });
```

Image below for full code visiblity:

[image]