# How to use TLS 1.2 in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, salesforce, asp.net-core-2.0

My salesforce res apis were working fine until. When suddenly I started getting authentication errors. **retry your request.**
**Salesforce.Common.AuthenticationClient.d__1.MoveNext()**.

salesforce informed that it would use from now TLS .1.2. How can I enforce my asp.net core 2.0 to use TLS 1.2 in Startup.cs. below is my code for login.

```
 private async Task<AuthenticationClient> GetValidateAuthentication()
        {
            RestApiSetting data = new RestApiSetting(Configuration);
            var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
            var url = data.IsSandBoxUser.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                ? "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
                : "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";
            try
            {
                //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(data.ConsumerKey,
                data.ConsumerSecret, data.Username, data.Password, url);
                return auth;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: maybe this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832384/any-way-to-restrict-asp-net-core-2-0-https-to-tls-1-2

Comment: This does not show me how and where to implement UseHttps.

Comment: For .net i used to run a registry entry there should be a similar way for .net core check the below page for the .net one
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1

Comment: I could not find any

Comment: AuthenticationClient is some class from salesforce library?

Comment: yes.it is.......

Comment: The strange bit is sometimes the authentication works sometimes it doesnot

Comment: I think .Net Core automatically uses TLS 1.2, so unline standard .Net you do not need the:
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
To make WebClient support/user TLS 1.2

Answer (score 20):

.net framework prior to version 4.7 makes outbound connections using TLS 1.0 by default. You can upgrade to a newer version to fix the problem, or alternatively, you can set the default and fallback versions for outbound calls using the ServicePointManager, or passing the setting into the HttpClient if you have the source code for the library.

Add the following somewhere early in your pipeline, such as your `startup.cs` or `global.asax`:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

You can find a good description on the topic here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8db54c83-1329-423b-8d55-4dc6a25fe826/how-to-make-a-web-client-app-use-tls-12?forum=csharpgeneral

And if you want to specify it only for some requests instead of application-wide, then you can customize the `HttpClientHandler` of your `HttpClient`:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
...
```

Comment: A note to others coming with 4.6.1 targeting issues where you may be dragging in deps to .netstandard as a result of other nuget packages. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` does not seem to work in some cases (due to binding conflict/resolution issue). Setting `HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols` explicitly and passing to `HttpClient` resolved this for me.

Answer (score 5):

According to the following 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29452

> In .NET Core, ServicePointManager affects only HttpWebRequest. It does not affect HttpClient. You should be able to use HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to achieve the same.

Comment: Then using Alexandru Puiu's method of customizing the handler for a specific HttpClient should work right?

Comment: ServerCertificateValidationCallback validates the certificate, SslProtocols sets the version of TLS to be used