# FAKE F# - enable TLS on https requests

Tags: tls1.2, f#-fake

I have some legacy code on F#

```
                let response = 
                    Http.Request (
                        ArtifactoryUrl, 
                        silentHttpErrors = true,
                        httpMethod = "POST", 
                        body = HttpRequestBody.TextRequest requestJson,
                        headers = [ 
                            HttpRequestHeaders.BasicAuth ArtifactoryUserName ArtifactoryPassword
                            HttpRequestHeaders.ContentType "application/json"
                            HttpRequestHeaders.Accept "application/json"
                        ]
                    )
```

Starting from some time, it failed with the following error

```
exception: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I suspect that it is due to recent web server limitation to TLS 1.2 only.
How can i fix it? How can i select TLS1.2 only?
Any help here will highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it happens because you are using old version of .net framework (less than 4.7).
If so, you can set the default and fallback versions for outbound calls using the ServicePointManager:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol <- SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ||| SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
```

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056328/3029359)