# GetConfigurationAsync for OpenIdConnectConfiguration returns Object reference not set exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, adal, identitymodel

I am running version 6.28.1 of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` in a 4.8 .NET Framework project.

Trying to get the configuration to validate a token and get an exception that I can't dig into:

```
var discoveryDocument = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(ct);
```

I have a `POC` sample of this code in a .NET6 project that works great, but when migrating this to my own application I can't get past this exception.

I tried downgrading to `5.5 version`, as well as upgrading to `6.29,` however I get the same errors no matter what I change.

Comment: where did you resolve configurationManager? outside of UseOpenIdConnect? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally since 18 Apr 2023 a similar issue started occurring for me, however might be unrelated to your issue. I wasted days on investigating where GetConfigurationAsync within OWIN never yielded with no logged error/warning, see https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dbe159e43e2eee44f315f26268943e8ab5a4f60d/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L148)

I finally found out that regardless of server best practice TLS configurations (which is TLS 1.2+), OWIN still contacts Microsoft's servers for pre-authentication configuration fetch (GetConfigurationAsync) via old TLS version (1.0 / 1.1)

Enforcement through machine registry entries will not work (will be ignored for unknown reasons). The only working method I found is to add to your application startup (Application_Start in Global.asax) a list of permitted TLS versions, like so

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

which is not recommended, since you lock-in the security protocols, but given the malfunction in the OWIN library a working trade-off.

Similar scenario: [Anyway to restrict Owin HTTPS to TLS 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992488/anyway-to-restrict-owin-https-to-tls-1-2)

Comment: This isn't specific to the OWIN libraries, this is about TLS defaults for all of .NET. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: 1. The TLS failure as part of GetConfigurationAsync was not reported by OWIN and I had to debug OWIN to find out
2. Server-wide prevention as per https://thesecmaster.com/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-on-windows-server/#Method_3_Disable_TLS_10_and_TLS_11_on_Windows_Server_using_CMD (i.e. reg keys) of old TLS was ignored