# Disable weaker TLS ciphers for a Linux hosted ASP.NET Core app

Tags: linux, .net-core, redhat, tls1.2

I am looking at disabling RC4 and 3DES TLS ciphers in my application and wondering how to implement this?

The application is Angular/ASP.NET Core currently in the latest versions of both technologies. The application is hosted on a Red Hat 7 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Application level

You may try to force your app to only support TLS 1.3.

[TLS 1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Cipher) supports only ciphers thought to be secure.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63389326/18516407) explains how to do it for TLS 1.2, you would just have to change the

```
s.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

to

```
s.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13;
```

More informations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-6.0)

Feel free to test it with [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

---

You can stay on TLS 1.2 and manually choosing your ciphers by doing this.

Proceed with absolute caution when doing this. **You want to do this only if you absolutely know what you're doing.**

```cs
var ciphersArray = new TlsCipherSuite[]
{
    TlsCipherSuite.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, // etc
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
{
    webHostBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(kestrelServerOptions =>
    {
        kestrelServerOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(w =>
        {
            w.OnAuthenticate = (x, s) =>
            {
                var ciphers = new CipherSuitesPolicy(ciphersArray);
                s.CipherSuitesPolicy = ciphers;
            };
        });
    });
});
```

---

## OS Level

It's not your OS version but this [RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening#cipher_suites_and_protocols_enabled_in_the_crypto_policies_levels) doc could be interesting to you. As you can see the `DEFAULT` option doesn't allow RC4 and 3DES

Comment: I have implemented the code above but when I run the tests it still shows those ciphers being offered. The VM is hosted in Azure, is there other things I will need to do on the Azure configuration side?